# Some directories empty in mounted NFS directory

Tags: debian, osx, nfs

From a client computer running macOS I connect to a directory on my Debian server on the local network using the address `nfs://192.168.0.14/mnt/archive/foo`. The strange thing is that some directories in `foo` are empty on the client but not on the server. All directories have the same permission and ownership. The only line in `/etc/exports` with the client IP address is

```
/mnt/archive/foo 192.168.0.17(ro,no_root_squash,insecure,subtree_check,fsid=0)
```

Any clues?

Edit: It turns out that only directories with non-ASCII characters in the filename appear empty. Therefor it seems like a character encoding issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client computer, add the line

```
nfs.client.mount.options = nfc
```

to the file `/etc/nfs.conf`. This tells macOS to normalize NFS paths using Normalization Form Canonical Composition (NFC).

https://j-li.net/posts/mounting-a-linux-nfs-on-osx